# numerical analysis equation

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I have this equation 
[image: here]
and 
then find the polynomial from 
[image: here]

I am trying to implement it like this:

```
for (int n=0;n<order;n++){
    df[n][0]=y[n];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){ //N number of points

        df[n][i]+=factorial(n,i)*y[i+n-1];
    }

    }

for (int i=0;i<N;i++){

    term=factorial(s,i);
    result*=df[0][i]*term;
    sum+=result;
    }

return sum;
```

1) I am not sure how to implement the sign of every argument in the function.As you can see it goes 'positive' , 'negative', 'positive' ...

2) I am not sure for any mistakes...

Thanks!

----------------------factorial-----------------------------

```
int fact(int n){
//3!=1*2*3
if (n==0) return 1;
else
return n*fact(n-1);

}

double factorial(double s,int n){
//(s 3)=s*(s-1)*(s-2)/6
if ((n==0) &&(s==0)) return 1;
else
    return fact(s)/fact(n);


}
```

Comment: `if(n%2==0) result *= -1.0` you need a line like this just after `result*=df[0][i]*term`. Alternatively you can use `result*=df[0][i]*term*(n%2==0?-1.0:1.0)`

Comment: @Dan Nice example of obfuscation.

Comment: @Dan:The positive-negative concept is in df argument and not in the result (which is df*term).So (and correct me if i mistake) i should out " if((i+n)%2!=0) y[i+n-1]= -1.0;" after the line "df[n][i]+=factorial(n,i)*y[i+n-1];", right?

Comment: @George oh, perhaps. I'm afraid I didn't pay too much attention to the actual equation.

Comment: @Dan, do you have a reference (bibliogr, WWW) to yours formulas. I cant understan your code, sorry, but I'm curious.

Comment: @qPCR4vir it's called the ternary operator. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B)

Comment: Uy, sorry... to calcule the sign I think what @James Kanze show is the best option.. I mean the original formula from George... sorry.

Comment: @qPCR4vir: Ok, it's for newton-gregory formula http://ecourses.vtu.ac.in/nptel/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/Numerical%20Analysis/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode8.html  , http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html

Comment: I saw a problem with the initialization of df[n][i] for i<>0

Comment: @qPCR4vir I agree, I believe `%` is quite slow plus using the ternary operator is not very readable. I was just presenting it as a terse option :)

Comment: @Dan : ;-)  OK, I have also added one terse option more,  please check if correct ... (last answer)

Comment: hmm.. thinking: what happen with your factorial(0.5 , 1)  ?? you see?

Comment: @qPCR4vir:Yes..it's a problem..

Comment: I agree it is not trivial. You need to sit down alone with a pencil and a sheet of paper. Test with small mummers and than debug and correct errors. (I did so !!). And make question again ;-)   -Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I understand you want to approximately calculate the value f(x) for a given x=X, using Newton Interpolation polynomial with equidistant points (more specifically Newton-Gregory forward difference interpolation polynomial).
Assuming s=(X-x0)/h, where x0 is the first x, and h the step to obtain the rest of the x for which you know the exact value of f :
Considere:

```
double coef (double s, int k)
{
    double c(1);
    for (int i=1; i<=k ; ++i)
        c *= (s-i+1)/i ;
    return c;
}

double P_interp_value(double s, int Num_of_intervals , double f[] /* values of f in these points */)    // P_n_s
{

    int N=Num_of_intervals ;

    double *df0= new double[N+1]; // calculing df only for point 0

    for (int n=0 ; n<=N ; ++n)  // n here is the order
    {
        df0[n]=0;
        for (int k=0, sig=-1; k<=n; ++k, sig=-sig) // k here is the "x point"
        {
            df0[n] += sig * coef(n,k) * f[n-k];
        }
    }

    double P_n_s = 0;

    for (int k=0; k<=N ; ++k )   // here k is the order
    {
        P_n_s += coef(s,k)* df0[k];
    }
    delete []df0;

    return P_n_s;
}


int main()
{
    double s=0.415, f[]={0.0 , 1.0986 , 1.6094 , 1.9459 , 2.1972 };

    int n=1; // Num of interval to use during aproximacion. Max = 4 in these example
    while (true)
    {
    std::cin >> n; 
    std::cout << std::endl << "P(n=" << n <<", s=" << s << ")= " << P_interp_value(s, n, f)  << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

it print:

1

P(n=1, s=0.415)= 0.455919

2

P(n=2, s=0.415)= 0.527271

3

P(n=3, s=0.415)= 0.55379

4

P(n=4, s=0.415)= 0.567235

compare with:
http://ecourses.vtu.ac.in/nptel/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/Numerical%20Analysis/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode8.html

It works. Now we can start to optimize these code.

Comment: :One question,Where you have df0[n] += sig * coef(n,k) * f[n-k]; , according to the equation i have above ,where it says f_i+n,f_i+n-1,f_i+n-2...If i have i=0 i am taking "f_n,f_n-1,f_n-2..".For i=1 f_n+1,f_n,f_n-1..For i=2 f_n+2,f_n+1,f_n,f_n-1...You have "n-k" which results to n-1,n-2,n-3..The n+1,n+2 values?I am a bit confused .thanks for the help!

Comment: I have noted, to calcule the result we need only df0 (point 0), and in these formula it corresponde to i=0. I calcule only these first term.

Comment: :I forgot.At the coef function are you sure it's ok?Because as i understand the (s k) = (s(s-1)..s-k+1)! / k! . The way you have it is (s k) = (s(s-1)..s-k+1)! / (s-k)!k!. Check my factorial function.

Comment: sorry.. where is your factorial ?

Comment: "The way you have it is (s k) = (s(s-1)..s-k+1)! / (s-k)!k! ". Why (s-k)!k!   ?  "My" i take the values from 1 to k.

Comment: @ qPCR4vir:sorry , i updated.Although i am confused about this  (s(s-1)..s-k+1)

Comment: :One last question .:) . In the loops you have <=N .Shouldn't that must be <N-1 because: N is the number of points and not the degree,so the polynomial should be N-1 order and because loop starts from 0 ,it should go i=0;i<N-1 and the double *df0= new double[N]; and not [N+1].

Comment: You are rigth. This was a bad name for these variable. The correct is Num_of_intervals = Num_of_points -1. But the code is correct.

Comment: @ qPCR4vir:So , where you have int N=Num_of_points it should be Num_of_points-1

Comment: No, I'm calling the function just with these maining: Num_of_intervals, with value Num_of_points-1. But we can use as you say and made the changes.

Comment: Simple in the example they numered the points starting from 0 -as in c+ :-). And for me was simpler to follow their conventions. This is the index of the last point.

Comment: You're welcome. Your question is much more interesting than many tasks asked here, with complicated logic but little sense (homeworks-like).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably to just keep the sign in
a variable, and multiply it in each time through the loop.
Something like:

```
sign = 1.0;
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++ i ) {
    term = factorial( s, i );
    result *= df[0][i] * term;
    sum += sign * result;
    sign = - sign;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for the tip.But can you check my comment above?I think i must use " if((i+n)%2!=0 " .

Comment: The results will be exactly the same.  Anytime you need to toggle the sign, toggle the sign, as above.  Testing whether the index is even or odd, using `i % 2 != 0`, is an alternative, but it should be reserved for cases where the difference in treatment is more than just toggling the sign.

Comment: :Ok for the first question.Do you think from the code i have done that it solves right the equatio?Thank you!

Comment: @James Kanze : I could not understand yours: result *= ... some optimization?

Comment: @qPCR4vir Copied from the original.  The example is just that: it shows `sign` being toggled.  I've not done any real analysis of the original code compared to the equations.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `pow( -1, m )`.

You can write your own:

```
inline int minusOnePower( unsigned int m )
{
    return (m & 1) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

You may want to build up some tables of calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

just for the sign ;-)

```
inline signed int minusOnePower( unsigned int m )
{
    return 1-( (m & 1)<<1 );
}
```